# how do I copy UITextField data into a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, uitextfield, uilabel

I have a textfield and a label.

When you touch the textfield, the keyboard appears

In IB, the textfield's properties are

Keyboard: ASCII Capable
Return Key: Done

I wired the IBOutlet to the label and the textfield.

How do I get the keyboard to go away when I'm done entering text.
How do I get to copy the text to the UIlabel?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you push the DONE Button, the `UITextField` sends a `-textFieldDidEndEdititing:` method to its delegate, which should be your controller instance.

This method simply moves the editor focus off the `UITextField` and thus makes the keyboard disappear. Then put the new values into the `UILabel`:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    label.text = textField.text;
}
```

Comment: How do I make a delegate? I don't think I've assigned a delegate.

Comment: The `delegate` is a property/outlet on the `UITextField` instance. Simply connect this outlet using the InterfaceBuilder with your controller instance which is normally represented by the "Files Owner" instance in the .XIB file.